# How to call a function from within another function?

Tags: python

I am creating a simple GUI program to manage priorities. I am having troubles with accessing a function from within another function. In my program, I tried to create an instance of the GuiPart class and then calling g.addItem but it doesn't seem to work like that. I am getting an error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py", line 70, in > <module>
   g.display()
 File "/home/cali/PycharmProjects/priorities/priorities.py", line 39, in > display
   command = g.addItem)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2077, in grid_configure
   + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-command": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, > -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

Here is what I have done:

```
# priorities.py
#   GUI program to manage priorities

from tkinter import *

class Priority:

    def __init__(self, subject, priority):
        self.subject = subject
        self.priority = priority

    def subject(self):
        return self.subject

    def priority(self):
        return self.priority


class GuiPart:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = self.createWindow()

    def createWindow(self):

        root = Tk()
        root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        root.title("Priorities")

        return root

    def createWidgets(self):

        listBox = Listbox().grid(row=1)

        buttonAdd = Button(text = "Add").grid(row = 2,
                                  column = 0,
                                  sticky = W,
                                  command = g.addItem)

        buttonRemove = Button(text="Remove").grid(row = 2,
                                   column = 0,
                                   sticky = W,
                                   command = g.removeItem)

        buttonEdit = Button(text="Edit").grid(row = 2,
                                 column = 0,
                                 sticky = E,
                                 command = g.editItem)

        textBox = Text().grid(row = 3)

    def addItem(self, item):
        item = Priority(item.subject, item.priority)
        item.subject = g.textBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c')

        g.listBox.insert(END, self)

    def removeItem(self):
       pass

    def editItem(self):
        pass

class Client:
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = GuiPart()
    g.createWidgets()
    g.root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `addItem` takes a parameter and you're not supplying it one by the looks of it

Comment: You're instantiating a `GuiPart` object as `g` but you also refer to `g` inside the class. They should be `self`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at part of your code...

```
    buttonAdd = Button(text = "Add").grid(row = 2,
                              column = 0,
                              sticky = W,
                              command = g.addItem)
```

The primary problem here is that `command` is a parameter to the `Button()` constructor, not the `.grid()` method.  That's where your current error is coming from.

The second problem is that the value you're assigning to `buttonAdd` is the result of `.grid()` (which is always `None`), NOT the button itself.  If you actually need a reference to the button for later use (often, you don't), this would have to be split up into two statements:

```
    buttonAdd = Button(text = "Add", command = g.addItem)
    buttonAdd.grid(row = 2,
                   column = 0,
                   sticky = W)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I cannot believe that I missed that.

Comment: If I don't have a reference to the button, how should I then point to the button which I want to grid?

Comment: You could do it in one line (like you originally did), just don't bother assigning the result to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
buttonAdd = Button(text = "Add").grid(row = 2,
                             column = 0,
                             sticky = W,
                             command = g.addItem)
#                                   ^^^^^^^^^

buttonRemove = Button(text="Remove").grid(row = 2,
                             column = 0,
                             sticky = W,
                             command = g.removeItem)
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^

buttonEdit = Button(text="Edit").grid(row = 2,
                            column = 0,
                            sticky = E,
                            command = g.editItem)
#                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

You are **not** calling functions you are **assigning** them.
In order to call them you have to pass parameter to them.

A small example explaining what happened:

```
>>> id(print)
1769760
>>> some_var = print
>>> id(some_var)
1769760
>>> some_var
<built-in function print>
>>> some_var('we assigned the built-in function "print" to the variable 
... some_var')
we assigned the built-in function "print" to the variable some_var
```

Comment: The OP doesn't WANT to call those functions - they're being set up to be called when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: @jasonharper You're right! The title says "call", wraith said he wants to "call"... So I focussed on "calling" a function :-D